# How does retiming work in systolic arrays?

Tags: signal-processing

How does retiming work in systolic arrays (used in signal processors)? I read that there is some notion of negative delay which is used, but how can a delay be negative and if that is just an abstraction then how does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic model of retiming is that you have wavefronts of registers interconnected by a bunch of combinational logic, and you are improving the timing or area of the resulting circuit by repositioning the registers at different points in the circuit such that every path through the logic still goes through the same number of registers.  For a simple example, lets say that you have an AND gate feeding a register, the longest path to the input of the register is 12ns, the longest path from the output of the register is 6ns, the delay of the AND gate is 3ns, and you need to get the clock cycle time down to 10ns.  You could achieve this by deleting the register and replacing it with two registers, one at each input of the AND gate, clocked by the same clock as the original register.  Now you have reduced the longest input path to 9ns, expanded the output path to 9ns, and met your clock cycle objective.  In effect, you have added -3ns to the effective arrival time at the register (and added +3 ns to the effective output time).

A modified version of Leiserson and Saxe's original paper on retiming is available [here](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/Compaq-DEC/SRC-RR-13.html).  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retiming) has a decent, though short, article on the subject with a few links.  If you have access to IEEE Xplore or the ACM Digital Library, a search through the proceedings of the Design Automation Conference or the International Conference on Computer-Aided Design looking for retiming should yield lots of articles - this has been an active research area for years.